# Problems of similar complexity for different measures

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

It is a common belief that $\mathbf{P}\subsetneq\mathbf{PSPACE}$, thus (most likely) there are problems that are "harder" for time than for space. But is there a problem in $\mathbf{P}$ with a poly-space lower bound (say for multi tape TM), i.e. is there a space-hard problem in $\mathbf{P}$?

Similarly, is there a problem in $\mathbf{P}$ with a good non-deterministic time lower bound? Is there a problem in $\mathbf{NP}$ with poly-space lower bound? ...

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please state it more  rigorously  mathematically?

Comment: Denis gave a good answer for the first and third question and I rephrased the second question for the clarity. For the second question, a good lower bound would be e.g. $\Omega(n^2)$.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still not sure what you are asking. You are using terms that I don't think are standard. What do you mean by "poly-space lower bound"? Are you asking if there is a problem in $P-DSpace(n^k)$ for some $k\geq 1$? What do you mean by "space-hard"? Do you mean PSpace-hard? And in the nondeterministic case, are you asking for a problem in $P-NTime(n^k)$ for some $k\geq 1$?

Comment: If a problem is outside $\mathbf{DSpace}(n^k)$, for some $k≥1$, then it has a "poly-space lower bound", just as you said. I called the problems outside $\mathbf{DSpace}(n^k)$, for some $k\geq 1$, space-hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the first question is that we don't know, because we don't know whether $\mathbf P=\mathbf L$, so it could be that all $\mathbf P$ problems use only logarithmic space.

For the second one, most reasonable problems need at least linear time to read the input, even for non-deterministic machines, so it does not make a lot of sense to say "polynomial non-deterministic lower bound", or you need to make your question more precise.

Finally, the last question is like the first one: it could be that $\mathbf{NL}=\mathbf{NP}$, in which case such a problem wouldn't exist, we don't know...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am a bit ashamed that I missed the open question P=L.

Comment: I also changed the second question a bit to avoid linear time lower bounds. But I guess that the answer to all my questions is "we do not know".

Comment: having said that, there are problems in P with (weak) super linear *time* lower bounds.